# Display message by popup in magento 2

Tags: magento2, popup

I have a module to download a file on S3 by magento 2. When I click button download, it will down a file csv, now I want if this file does not exist so display a popup message on screen by 1 notification sentence and 1 button OK. How can I do that? Help me!!! Tks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call **showcartPopup(msg)** this function to show a popup with a message when file not found. You just need to pass a message with a function. you can update class and function name according to you. I used this code for cart product success/failed message show

```
<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">
    <h2 id="cartmessagecustome" ></h2>
</div>

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
            $("#popup-modal").on('click',function(){
                $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
    function showcartPopup(msg){
        require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
            $('#cartmessagecustome').empty();
            $('#cartmessagecustome').append(msg);
            $('#popup-modal').click();
         });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: sorry I'm newbie so I can't do it yet, my work is: when I go on module, nothing to happen, when I select option and click button download that thing to do: if file exist, file is downloaded, if doesn't exist show alert popup..

Comment: can you please share your code which you added for popup

Comment: http://codepad.org/7mW0evmX (this is app/code/vender/module/view/adminhtml/templates/download.phtml)
http://codepad.org/KQZrsXTQ (this is app/code/vender/module/Controller/Adminhtml/Download/index.php)

Comment: Where did you mention popup code

Comment: I not sure I mention it where. I think I will mention in index.php\function download(): if (have file) -> download, else -> popup

Comment: you need to add code when your script returns that file not found. 

For example, you can add in ajax return if your script checking file by ajax

Comment: Tks for your help. I did it !!!

Comment: how did you do this

Comment: I follow 1st answer on my topic..

Comment: good then please accept that answer on your question it will help in future for anyone

Comment: How can I accept on this?

Answer (score 1):

> You need to check csv file is exist or not into if condition And for call Popup use this code init.

```
 if (file exist){

        //ADD your Doownload Logic

 } else {

?>
 <div id='popup-modal'>
        <h1> Hi I'm here.... </h1>
    </div>
    <script>
        require(
            [
                'jquery',
                'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
            ],
            function(
                $,
                modal
            ) {
                var options = {
                    type: 'popup',
                    responsive: true,
                    innerScroll: true,
                    title: 'popup modal title',
                    buttons: [{
                        text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                        class: '',
                        click: function () {
                            this.closeModal();
                        }
                    }]
                };
    
                var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
    
                $('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
            }
        );
    </script>
<?php
 
 }

?>
```

Comment: sorry I'm newbie so I can't do it yet, my work is: when I go on module, nothing to happen, when I select option and click button download that thing to do: if file exist, file is downloaded, if doesn't exist show alert popup..

Comment: :( I can't. I follow like you, but when I click button download, the popup display about 1s and then back to this screen

Comment: how can that show popup content and button OK? :( your recommend doesn't work for me

Comment: Sorry, I replaced but it isn't work

Comment: and an other question @Msquare :D  I'm a newbie so tell me how can I "accpet" as green tik mark for you?

Comment: I replaced text: $.mage.__('OK'), and run CLI commands, but I don't  know where I can replace name like you say? pls tell me..

Comment: Sorry but I still haven't done it :(